# Cannot launch RStudio 1.2.1335 on Fedora 29

Tags: r, rstudio, fedora, fedora-29

I used RStudio Desktop 1.1.463 on my Fedora 29 without problems. I use R version 3.5.3. A new version of RStudio is available (1.2.1335) and after installation through .rpm and clicking on app symbol in Menu, like before, nothing happens. I get no error, no message, nothing, so cannot really pinpoint to anything. I know that the installation was successful since the icon logo was updated.

Comment: Installing `compatopenssl10` may help; see the discussion at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4612)

Answer (score 0):

Download the **Zip/Tarball** from the rstudio website https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download

Open a terminal and extract e.g.

```
tar xzfv rstudio-1.2.1335-x86_64-fedora.tar.gz
```

Then run

```
./rstudio-1.2.1335/bin/rstudio
```

Check if you get any specific error.

It runs fine for me on Fedora 29 with 5.1.11-200.fc29.x86_64